# Should I include high school details in Grad School Resume?

Tags: graduate-school, graduate-admissions, cv

I was wondering if I should include my high school details in the resume of my graduate school application ? It's unclear about this bit since we are not actually submitting any proof of high school records during grad school application( they only ask for undergraduate details).
But my high school final examination details are particularly good (better than my undergraduate credentials infact!)

Comment: I don't know where you live, but probably comparing one high school with another is like comparing apples with oranges. Who reads your resume will probably not know about the quality of that high school, it will mean nothing to them, therefore, unless there is some normalized thing that is equal for everybody (a test, exam, whatever) I'd say no.

Comment: @Trylks I thought so too. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: I still list the name of my high school (and location and dates attended) on most versions of my CV. I feel like it potentially tells people a little bit about who I am.

Comment: I had differential equations, abstract algebra and introduction to topology on my high school transcript. I am kinda proud of As in these... although I have to admit I got a B in stereometry.

Comment: what if I won the 3rd, 6th, and 10th place of mathematics and physics national contests?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have to disagree slightly with the stark "No" answers.

**Only when those details provide evidence of your potential for *research*.**

*Some* information about your high-school experience *may* shed light on your research potential.  Certainly you would want to mention winning the [Intel Science Talent Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Science_Talent_Search) or the [International Olympiad in Informatics](http://ioinformatics.org/index.shtml), or describe the peer-reviewed research papers you published as a high school student.

But your high school *grades*?  No, leave them off.

Comment: Thanks! That more or less summed up the rest of the answers too.

Comment: I agree to the exceptions - prestigious awards and research papers. I'd like to ask some question for the applicants. Should they list the awards under 'Awards' category or high school? If the applicant has published peer-review papers while in high school, should he list them under 'Papers' category or high school?

Comment: @JeffE That's an interesting question scaaahu raised. I have another related question. Instead of putting my research stuff I did at high school in my CV,  wouldn't it look better in a research statement or Statement of Purpose. Otherwise, wouldn't specifying it under awards in CV confuse the AdComs as there is no mention of my high school credential here?

Comment: @scaaahu I'm not sure what "listing the awards under high school" would mean.  If you have an Awards section, that's obviously where you should list your awards; who should indicate their date, which will make it clear that they are from when you were in high school.  Similarly, all your peer-reviewed papers should be listed together; the date will make things clear.

Comment: Academia, like sports and show business, is really a "what have you done lately?" business. You're only as good as your last show, season, year of school. Listen to all the advice given by the responders. Above all, don't do anything that establishes a negative trend line (as Scaachu) has warned.

Comment: the comments are great. Can you answer those, @JeffE?

Comment: @Ooker — As Ben Webster says, all awards should be listed under "Awards", and all publications should be listed under "Publications".  Nobody will be confused, but if you want to be _sure_, you could list your high school under "Education".  I disagree with Chris Leary: Your CV is supposed to be a **complete** list of your academic accomplishments, not just what you've done lately.

Answer (score 19):

**No**

You already explain why: *they only ask for undergraduate details*. The graduate school admission committees already have too many applications to look at. Don’t over-load them

Your idea is actually counter-productive. If your high school record is better than your undergrad credentials, they would wonder why your academic achievement is regressing instead of progressing.

Comment: I would think if someone was valedictorian of a large high school class, that would give good insight into the type of person they are.

Comment: @James I wouldn't recommend it.  Probably not a big deal either way, but I don't think committees will see the skills of being valedictorian as having much to with success as a grad student.  Besides, if your work at university is of comparable quality that will be sufficient on its own, and if it isn't then knowing you were a success in high school will not help much.

Answer (score 6):

No.

It's actually a bad idea to include documents which are not actually required. Some universities even specifically mention not to send documents which are not required.

And also as @scaahu explained, it will give an negative impact as you did poorly in undergraduate compared to high school.

Answer (score 1):

I won't do that. 
it is a waste of time. for a master's degree and pHD, I would use only my university achievement. 
Completing graduate studies gives an employer a positive signal.
However, social conditions (different in each country) may oblige you to write your previous education.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily the answer is no, because it is no longer relevant to your aptitude for college, let alone graduate studies.

But if you won some national (or even local) science fair award for research in your current (or a related field), that would be relevant.

Answer (score -3):

I think that someone should include an accomplishment such as "valedictorian" on a resume, if nothing else from high school.  I would especially do this if the high school was quite large.  I was the valedictorian at a large high school and I put it on my resume even though I have completed graduate school.  I have received negative feedback from a few people about it, but when I looked up their backgrounds, they didn't have any accomplishments even similar to those that I have at all... I mean, these people didn't even have a 3.0 GPA in college.  Therefore, I chalked the "stark NO" responses to jealousy.  People with similar accomplishments to mine seem to have no problem with me putting that one accomplishment from high school on my resume.

Comment: If someone put on their professional resume that they received gold stars during art time in kindergarten, other people telling them not to include it on their resume are **not** doing so out of jealousy, no matter whether you can find evidence of similar accomplishments.