# How do grad schools view early High School graduation?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I graduated from High School after only 2 years and because of that I don't have a record of extra curricular activities and I also can't get most scholarships/grants because most require doing something for 3 years.

Anyway, I'm finishing up my undergrad and am looking into pursing a graduate degree. Does graduating early from High School put my at a disadvantage because I didn't do any extracurricular activities? I was always told while in High School that you need 3 years of a language and 2 years of EC activities to get into a Grad program.

Comment: Related question: [Should I include high school details in Grad School Resume?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13872/546).

Comment: well that's impressive! Be sure to be prepared at the interviews though, or you'll risk to disappoint :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Graduate schools do not generally care about an applicant's high school record, unless the applicant has some exceptional achievement from high school. Applications to graduate school won't even require high school transcripts.

In particular, graduate schools generally do not care at all about non-academic extra-curricular activites, whether in high school or afterwards. See [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9484/do-non-academic-extra-curricular-activities-matter-for-grad-school-applications) for more details.

Comment: They care if it is relevant to research where you applying. See http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/13886/9009

Comment: @Léo The examples mentioned there are examples of what I refer to in this answer as "exceptional achievement": "unless the applicant has some exceptional achievement"